# Integrating with respect to time: $dx/dt=a$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, physics

If $a$ is a constant and $dx/dt=a$, then integrating with respect to time gives $x = x_0 + at$. How do we show that?

Is my reasoning correct?

> $dx/dt=a \implies \int_{0}^{t} dx(t) = a\int_{0}^{t} dt \implies x(t) - x(0) = at \implies x = x_0 + at$

Comment: As a physicist by training there is nothing wrong with that slight of hand - however $$\int \frac{dx}{dt}dt = \int a dt$$ is what you should think.

Comment: I suggest not trying to interpret $dx/dt$ as a fraction and not confusing the $dt$ in $dx/dt$ from differentiation with the $dt$ in $\int dt$ in integration. There are ways to do that, but they require careful definitions and a very precise understanding. In the meantime, don't do it, it'll just make everything more confusing. Also, $\int_0^t dt$ doesn't make sense, $t$ cannot be at the same time an integration bound and the variable of integration.

Comment: Sure, that's correct. Personally, I wouldn't equivocate between $x$ and $x(t)$, even though that's common among physicists: I'd either write $x(t)$ always, so that the conclusion is $x(t)=x(0)+at$ (or $x(t)=x_0+at$ if you write $x_0$ for $x(0)$, although that hardly seems necessary); or write $x$ always so that the next-to-last step is $x-x|_{t=0}=at$, and then you really will want to write $x_0$ for $x|_{t=0}$ so that the final conclusion is $x=x_0+at$. But, as I said, the way you wrote it would also be understood, especially by physicists and applied mathematicians generally.

Comment: Also, you should know the meaning of an expression like $\int_0^t\,f(t)\mathrm dt$, which is formally defined as $\int_0^t\,f(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau$ with a different dummy variable. Another way to write this is as $\int_0\,f(t)\,\mathrm dt$, which is called a semidefinite integral (see Section 5.4 on page 46 [here](http://tobybartels.name/calcbook/single.pdf#page=46)); I prefer this, although it isn't widely known. Your notation is, again, something that physicists will recognize and use a lot.

Comment: @Chinny84 Thanks for the reminder. After $\int \frac{dx}{dt}dt = \int a dt$, I think we get $\int dx = \int a dt$. Am I right?